# How do I change the color of text on a WTForm? (python, html)

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

So I am trying to create a Flask app.

Here is a section of my html:

```
<div class = "card-body">
      <div>
         {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
         {{ render_field(form.email, class = "form-control") }}
         {{ render_field(form.password, class = "form-control") }}
         {{ render_field(form.remember_me, class = "form-control") }}
         {{ render_field(form.submit, class = "btn btn-primary") }}
      </div>
```

and here is my python file where I named the input fields:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, BooleanField, IntegerField, PasswordField, SubmitField, TextAreaField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, length, email, EqualTo


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField("Email", validators = [DataRequired(), email()])
    password = PasswordField("Password", validators = [DataRequired()])
    remember_me = BooleanField("Remember Me")
    submit = SubmitField("Login")
```

I connected them through some other files and its all fine, all I need to do is change the color of the text in the python file.
For example,
lass LoginForm(FlaskForm):

```
  email = StringField("Email", validators = [DataRequired(), email()])
```

The "email" which shows on my form as the title of the input place, is currently black, how do I make it white?

I altered the input place using the form control class and stuff, but am confused with the text above it because they are string in the python file.

Answer (score 0):

So for this you have to create one directory named "**templates**" and in that create one css file eg- **style.css** and in that you can do your styling.
You can go through the documentation https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/tutorial/css/

Comment: im sorry that wasn't my question though, I know about the styling methods and stuff  and I have a <style> open in my html but what is confusing me is, what name should I use to style them? like to style the form itself I used .form-control{} and described what I wanted, but for the field titles, there is no class to them, they are just render_field, so what should I use to refer to them?